# Application form Validation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys i am trying to do some validation in application form.

I have 3 text box for different mobile numbers like home, work, Mobile like this.. i need 1 field compulsory of 3. User must have to enter at least 1 number of 3.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please clear that you know how to validate one and want the condition for validation of three or want the whole thing!

Comment: @Dipali - Please accept the solution that is useful to you! It will benefit others. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try code like given below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function checkValidation(){
            var mobile = document.getElementById('mobile').value;
            var gome = document.getElementById('home').value;
            var work = document.getElementById('work').value;
            var error_count = 0;

            if(mobile == ''){
                error_count = error_count + 1;   
            } 
            if(home == ''){
                error_count = error_count + 1;   
            } 
            if(work == ''){
                error_count = error_count + 1;   
            } 

            if(error_count == 3){
                 alert("Please add at least one from mobile ,work,home contact no.! ");
                 return false;
             }else{
                   return true; 
             }
       }
 </script>
```

You can try something like this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you for what you are looking for. if you html form on submit calls validation() function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validation() {
  var a = document.form.phone.value;
  var b = document.form.mobile.value;
  var c = document.form.home.value;
  if(a=="" && b =="" && c =="") {
    alert("Please Enter at least one Number");
    //add other validation if you need here
    document.form.phone.focus(); // focus the first field for example
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not compare the input value to "" or '' . The user can simply type blank spaces. Instead check for or trim white spaces and check that it is a valid number.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Check for all whitespace.
function hasWhiteSpace(s){
    return /^\s+$/g.test(s);
}

//Check for valid number
function isNumber(n) {
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function validation(){
    var mobile = document.getElementById('mobile').value;
    var home = document.getElementById('home').value;
    var work = document.getElementById('work').value;

    var error = 0;

    if(!(!hasWhiteSpace(mobile) && isNumber(mobile))){
        error += 1;   
    } 
    if(!(!hasWhiteSpace(home) && isNumber(home))){
        error += 1;      
    } 
    if(!(!hasWhiteSpace(work) && isNumber(work))){
        error += 1;   
    } 

    if(error == 3){
        alert("You must enter at least one contact number.");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true; 
    }
}
</script>
```

Call validation() from your form onsubmit.

```
<form onsubmit="return validation();">
```

[JavaScript Number Validation](http://www.philipstarritt.com/jsnumbervalidator.php)

[JavaScript Check For White Space](http://www.philipstarritt.com/jswhitespacevalidator.php)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

jQuery in case you want it

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/cm9Vj/)

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
  Home <input type="phone" class="phones"><br/>
  Work <input type="phone" class="phones"><br/>
  Mobile <input type="phone" class="phones"><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
​
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#form1").on("submit",function() {
        var notempty = $(".phones[value!='']"); // you can extend this test
        if (notempty.length<1) {
            alert('Please fill at least one number');
            $(".phones:first").focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}); ​
```